# PHP MySQLi doesn't execute INSERT query

Tags: php, mysql

**I had a false redirect. But the system won't let me delete the question**
I have a website with a register page. In the backend is a SQL database, but while UPDATE and SELECT work, INSERT doesn't. IT also doesn't give me any errors.

The code which makes the INSERT statement looks as follows:

```
$username = "peter";
$pwhash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$role = "publisher";
$locked = "false";

//Prepare SQL Query
$sql = "insert into user(username, password, role, locked)";
$sql .= " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";

//Reuire SQL Connection
require "db_inc.php";

//Prepare stmt
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);

//Bind Parameters
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssss',    
                                        $username,
                                        $pwhash,
                                        $role,
                                        $locked);

//Execute SQL
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);


mysqli_close($con);
```

The SQL database looks like this:
[image: SQL Database]

What am I doing wrong? The $con connection is correct, as it workes on the SELECT and UPDATE querys.

Comment: What is in the ENUM?

Comment: ENUM("admin", "publisher") @TimothyLukasH.

Comment: @Tim What are the return values of your `mysqli_prepare()`, `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` and `mysqli_stmt_execute()` calls? Output them with `var_dump();` and [edit] your question to include the output. Also, include the output of `var_dump(mysqli_error($con));`.

Comment: @Progman I just noticed something strange. The SQL query above is a function of a class which returns true when successful. In the file where I call the function, nothing will happen when it is successfull. But still it redirects me to the start page. So I will need to fix that first

Comment: It was something completly diffrent... I didn't redirect my form to register, but rather to the main page. Sorry.

Comment: Error reporting link for mysqli http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried capitalizing 'insert'? And try changing '$locked = "false";' to'$locked = 0';

Comment: `insert` doesn't need to be capitalized. That is developers preference.

Comment: as @user3783243 captializing doesn't matter and I've allready tried using 0. Even if I don't bind the zero and write it into the query string it won't work

Comment: It was something completly diffrent... I didn't redirect my form to register, but rather to the main page. Sorry.